# CSS Multiple :not with mixed selector types

Tags: css

I want to mark external links for a site with a special icon. But not for a specific class or id.

```
a[href^="http://"]:not([href*="sitename.com"]):not(classname or id):before,
a[href^="https://"]:not([href*="sitename.com"]):not(classname or id):before
{
   content: '\f08e';
   font-family: "fontawesome";
   color: #019fe0;
   padding-right: 4px;
}
```

but it marks them all, even those with the classname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mark external links for a site **but not *sitename.com*** (for example) with a special button that does **not** have an id named ***someId*** (for example), this is the way to do it

```
a[href^="http://"]:not([href*="sitename.com"]):not(#someId),
a[href^="https://"]:not([href*="sitename.com"]):not(#someId) {
    /* CSS properties */
}
```

If you want to mark external links to ***sitename.come*** (for example) with a special button that does have an id name ***idName*** (for example), this is the way to do it

```
a[href^="http://"][href*="sitename.com"]#idName,
a[href^="https://"][href*="sitename.com"]#idName {
    /* CSS properties */
}
```

I've made a Fiddle to demonstrate this answer: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v527syuk/)

---

In case you meant *classname OR id* as some sort of a selector:

```
a[href^="http://"]:not([href*="sitename.com"]):not(#someId):not(.some-class),
a[href^="https://"]:not([href*="sitename.com"]):not(#someId):not(.some-class) {
    /* CSS properties */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that great fiddle, but i think my problem ist that the code didn't work because the id or class is in a parent container. So i think, there is no way to catch, correct? :-(

Comment: If your element is inside that container you can say `#id a[href...`, if there's an element inside the `<a>` that you want to style you can say `a[href^="http://"][href*="sitename.com"] #idName` (notice the space). There's always a way! Let me know if this helps or update your question with more detailed information!

Comment: @Regnalf I also edited my answer. Maybe this is what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but that is exactly what i did now as a workaround. Catch all "a" elements in the containers where i want it. If i want to ecxlude it there i must set an extra css line for that specific element. But again, thanks for that nice fiddle

Comment: Glad I could help! Goodluck